# Xamarin: OnTimedEvent() Not Firing (TIMERS)

Tags: c#

I have been doing this x times, but today, it decided not to work. Maybe I've gotten blind? Simple piece of code:

```
    private TextView txt;
    private Timer _timer;
    private int seconds; 

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        txt = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.testTextView);
        seconds = 0;
        Timer();
    }

    void Timer()
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 100;
        _timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        seconds += 1;
        CountDown(); 
    }

    void CountDown()
    {
        txt.Text = seconds.ToString();
    }
```

But `OnTimedEvent` is NOT getting called. NEVER. WHY?!

Comment: now it gets more and more wierd: i cant set breakpoints...

Comment: I am in debug. I have restarted my pc and now I can set breakpoints again! (Never had this happen before...) Anyway: I am hitting the breakpoint once. Still the ontimedevent is not happening...

Comment: Something I just witnessed: whenever i put the app in the backrgound and then return the countdown did seem to work. i just eddited the questions and set the countdown method. I just want the text in the layout to add 1 every .1 seconds. whenever i put the app into the background and then return the number on th text changed. so what exactly is going on here xD

Comment: We need a [mcve] to help you.

Comment: Okay here is something else that I noticed: The countdown does infact work, but for somereason I cannot change the contents of a textview from inside of the ontimedevent. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, I found it out:
The timer was working, but i wasn't able to change UI elements from not ui threads. UNLESS I do this:

```
        RunOnUiThread(() => txt.Text = seconds.ToString());
```

And there we go:)